# Regex - Grep the specifc NTP IP addresses

Tags: linux, grep

```
[root etc]# grep "^server" /etc/ntp.conf
server 10.10.10.2
server 10.10.11.3
server 10.12.13.4

[root etc]# grep "^\s*server (10\.10\.10\.2|10\.10\.11\.3)" /etc/ntp.conf
[root etc]# (Nothing return)
```

Show nothing, how can I grep the specifc IP addresses?

Comment: grep is not regexes. It is glob. Use egrep or the `-E` modifier for regexes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to add `-E` to your grep command.

```
grep -E "^\s*server (10\.10\.10\.2|10\.10\.11\.3)" /etc/ntp.conf
```

Comment: Thanks~ i missed the "E"

Answer (score 1):

Use grep -E with a pipe separator for OR

```
grep -E "^server 10.10.10.2|^server 10.10.11.3" /etc/ntp.conf
```

Answer (score 1):

The following reads the search strings from standard input.

```bash
grep -F "$(awk NF </dev/stdin)" /etc/ntp.conf | grep -P '^\s*server\s+'
```

- `grep -F` searches for fixed strings
- `$(... </dev/stdin)` - reads from standard input until `Ctrl-D` pressed
- `awk NF` removes blank lines
- `grep -P '^\s*server\s+'` searches for `server` entries from the previous `grep` output

Comment: Nice for interactive mode~ Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can use simple pattern like below:

```
   grep 10.10.10.*  filename
```

Or you have to use `-E` for extended regexp like below:

```
   grep -E 10.10.\(10\|11\).*  filename
```